# auth on msa2324fc via xml api failed

Tags: hp, storage-area-network, hp-modular-smart-array

I'll try to use my script ( which has been written for msa p2000 g3 ) with old san array msa2324. It seems like array actually do authorization and return session key, but my next request ( with sessionKey cookie ) still returns `Unauthorized access requested`. See screenshots below

I had rebooted both management controllers, one by one, but problem stil actual. I even use administration account in script - auth fail again

**Has anyone description of xml api protocol for msa2324?**

or, please name any soft that work with msa2324 via xml api - i self can find answer in network dump :)

screenshots with wireshark "follow tcp stream" window for old ( auth fail )  and new ( auth pass ) devices

- msa2324fc, old array, authorization failed

[image]

- msa p2000 g3, new array, authorization pass

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround: use telnet instead of http access. Code for telnet login is trivial

To get answers in XML format, first use command

```
set cli-parameters api pager off
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a cookie to your request containing two elements, wbiusername and wbisession key.
eg,
wbiusername=manage; wbisessionkey=b19ec2e62b49ba39f019ab187ea5efcb

I keep the sessionKey header in addition to the cookie to support these older MSAs in addition to the newer ones, works a treat and I don't have to resort to telnet.